# Вывод изображения через img в echo PHP

Tags: php

Есть код php который находится внутри html, ругается на строчку с тегом img, что здесь не так?

```php
<?php
    $dbUser = 'xxx';
    $dbName = 'yyy';
    $dbPass = 'zzz';
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
    $query = "SET something utf8";
    $mysqli->query($query);
    $query = "SELECT * from something";
    $results = $mysqli->query($query);
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "
        <div onclick='location.href='card.php';' class='product'>
            <div class='product-img'>
                <img src='.$row["ImgFile"].'>
                <div class='description'>
                    <a href='' class='price'>.$row["price"].</a><br>
                    <a href='' class='name'>.$row["name"].</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        ";
    }
?>
```

Comment: код в вопросе нужно добавлять кодом в не скриншотом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: У вас до и после этого куска `.$row["imgFile"].` не хватает кавычек. В будущем, пожалуйста, вставляйте код в виде текста и никогда не выкладывайте каких-либо паролей в сеть. В куске кода, связанном с `card.php` у вас тоже будет ошибка в разметке, связанная с кавычками. Вместо одинарных, нужно использовать экранированные двойные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Т.к. переменная **уже** находится в строке, которая начинается с двойных кавычек, то интерпретатор считает двойные кавычки у массива как закрытие строки и открытие новой.
Вам надо закрыть и открыть строку в другом месте:

```
src='" . $row['imgFile'] . "'>
```

Тоже самое с другими местами применения массива.

А ещё можно вставлять переменные прямо в строку вот так

```
src='{$row["imgFile"]}'>
```

А ещё можно использовать **[HEREDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)** bи **[NOWDOC](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)**